# Advertising a job in open source software and hardware

Tags: software, project-management, hardware

I am developing a solution to deploy open-source hardware in a way that would be similar to APT or Portage in software. As a matter of fact, the idea is to extend something like Portage to make it compatible with hardware deployment in parallel with software.
I started this project some time ago and I have an opportunity to recruit someone to help, but I am not sure where to advertise this job. This is a rather focused profile I need, and dedicated forums tend not to approve of job advertisement.
So my question is: where could I advertise a job in open source software/hardware?

Comment: Do you intend to pay "market rates" for the skill set you hire? (i.e. you won't expect your employee to take a discount because "open source is good")

Comment: The salary would be aligned on academics salary grid in the UK, as this is a research project for now. I should have mentioned it!

Answer (score 3):

There are some job boards focused on open source:

- [fossjobs.net](https://fossjobs.net) (the website itself is [open source](https://github.com/fossjobs/fossjobs), too!)
- [opensourcejobhub.com](https://opensourcejobhub.com)
- [fossfox.com](https://fossfox.com)

Just for completeness, I'll also mention a couple such projects that have since gone extinct/inactive:

- [osjobs.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20180303054720/https://www.osjobs.net/)
- [Jobs in open source](https://twitter.com/JobsOpenSource) (Twitter profile)